# Cant find Exact Error Line Number in the Console

Tags: java, android

[image]

here console show ClassCastException but  not show error line Number? Any one help me here?

if any one has idea about to find exact errorline number then suggest me plz?

here xml where i used ListView.

i have tried

1) removed Params which set by programatically

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/adlayout"
        android:background="@color/md_white_0">

        <com.os.folder.and.file.locker.files.widget.BGridView
            android:id="@+id/hide_view_list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:numColumns="3"
            android:stretchMode="columnWidth" />

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/hide_btn_add"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:background="@color/file_add"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_action_new" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/file_bottom_layout_tips"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/unrecord" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/file_bottom_txt_tips"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="64dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text=""
                android:textColor="@color/md_black_2"
                android:textSize="14sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/pic_hide_btn_edit"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/title_height"
        android:layout_above="@+id/adlayout"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@color/md_black_1"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:weightSum="4">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/pic_hide_img_cancel"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/title_height"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:onClick="onClick">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/close" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/title_height"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center">

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/item_file_checkbox"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:button="@drawable/checkbox_selector" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/pic_hide_img_recovery"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/title_height"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:onClick="onClick">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/unlock" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/pic_hide_img_del"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/title_height"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:onClick="onClick">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/delete" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/adlayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

here Java file, i have implemented from here listView

```
package com.os.folder.and.file.locker.files.activity;

import android.content.Intent;
import com.os.folder.and.file.locker.R;
import com.os.folder.and.file.locker.data.GroupImage;
import com.os.folder.and.file.locker.data.HideImage;
import com.os.folder.and.file.locker.files.adapter.BaseHideAdapter.OnListener;
import com.os.folder.and.file.locker.files.adapter.PicHideAdapter;
import com.os.folder.and.file.locker.files.entity.HideImageExt;
import com.os.folder.and.file.locker.files.widget.BGridView;
import com.os.folder.and.file.locker.service.GroupImageService;
import com.os.folder.and.file.locker.service.ImageService;

import java.util.List;

public class PicHideActivity extends BaseHideActivity implements OnListener {
    protected static final String TAG = "PicHideActivity";
    private int itemSize;
    protected GroupImageService mGroupImageService;
    protected ImageService mImageService;

    protected void initUI() {
        setContentView((int) R.layout.activity_file_hide_group);
        setUI();
        setTitleRID(R.string.pic_preview_title, R.string.pic_preview_title_edit);
        setGridView();

        this.mFile_bottom_txt_tips.setText(R.string.file_hide_txt_add_pic);
        this.rid_string_type = R.string.pic_preview;
    }

    private void setGridView() {
        this.itemSize = ((BGridView) findViewById(R.id.hide_view_list)).setGridView(getWindowManager(), 4, 4);

    }

    void initAdapter() {
        BGridView adapterView = findViewById(R.id.hide_view_list);
        this.mGroupImageService = new GroupImageService(this);
        this.mImageService = new ImageService(this);
        this.mBaseHideAdapter = new PicHideAdapter(this, this, this.itemSize);
        adapterView.setAdapter(this.mBaseHideAdapter);
    }

    boolean delFolder() {
        return false;
    }

    void addFolder() {}

    public void addFile() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, PicPreViewActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("beyondGroupId", this.mBaseHideAdapter.getGruopID());
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    protected void recoveryFiles() {
        for (Object imageModelView: this.mBaseHideAdapter.getHitFiles()) {
            this.mImageService.unHideImage((HideImageExt) imageModelView);
        }
    }

    protected void delFiles() {
        for (Object hideImageExt: this.mBaseHideAdapter.getHitFiles()) {
            this.mImageService.deleteAudioByPath((HideImageExt)
            hideImageExt);
        }
    }

    protected void openHolder(int groupID) {
        List < GroupImage > groupList = this.mGroupImageService.getGroupFiles(groupID);
        List < HideImage > list = this.mImageService.getHideImages(groupID);
        this.mBaseHideAdapter.setHitFiles(groupList, list, groupID);
        setHasData(groupList, list);
    }

    public void openHolder(Object object) {
        GroupImage data = (GroupImage) object;
        int groupID = -1;
        if (data != null) {
            groupID = data.getId().intValue();
        }
        openHolder(groupID);
    }
}
```

and here is adapter code,

```
package com.os.folder.and.file.locker.files.adapter;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.View.OnLongClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
//import android.widget.AbsListView.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.DisplayImageOptions;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.DisplayImageOptions.Builder;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.ImageLoader;
import
com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.download.ImageDownloader.Scheme;
import com.os.folder.and.file.locker.R;
import com.os.folder.and.file.locker.data.GroupImage;
import com.os.folder.and.file.locker.data.HideImage;
import com.os.folder.and.file.locker.files.activity.PhotoPreViewActivity;
import com.os.folder.and.file.locker.files.entity.GroupImageExt;
import com.os.folder.and.file.locker.files.entity.HideImageExt;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class PicHideAdapter extends BaseHideAdapter {
    private static final String TAG = "PicHideAdapter";
    protected ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
    DisplayImageOptions options = new Builder().showStubImage(R.drawable.default_picture).showImageForEmptyUri((int) R.drawable.default_picture).showImageOnFail((int) R.drawable.default_picture).cacheInMemory(true).cacheOnDisc(true).build();
    private ViewGroup.LayoutParams params;

    class PicHolder {
        Object mData;
        ImageView mImg_pre_preview;
        View mItem_file_ok;
        View mItem_file_pic;

        PicHolder() {}
    }

    public PicHideAdapter(Context context, OnListener onListern, int itemSize) {
        super(context, onListern);
        this.params = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(itemSize, itemSize);
    }

    public void clear() {
        super.clear();
        if (this.imageLoader != null) {
            this.imageLoader.stop();
            this.imageLoader = null;
        }
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = this.mInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_file_hide_pic, null);
            PicHolder picHolder = new PicHolder();
            picHolder.mItem_file_pic = convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_file_pic);
            picHolder.mItem_file_ok = convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_file_ok);
            picHolder.mImg_pre_preview = (ImageView)
            convertView.findViewById(R.id.img_pre_preview);
            convertView.setTag(picHolder);
            // convertView.setLayoutParams(this.params);
        }
        initView(convertView, position);
        return convertView;
    }

    protected void initView(View view, final int position) {
        int i = 8;
        final PicHolder fileHolder = (PicHolder) view.getTag();
        fileHolder.mImg_pre_preview.setImageBitmap(null);
        Object data = getItem(position);
        fileHolder.mData = data;
        if (data instanceof HideImageExt) {
            final HideImageExt hideImageView = (HideImageExt) data;
            this.imageLoader.displayImage(Scheme.THUMBNAIL.wrap(hideImageView.getNewPathUrl()), fileHolder.mImg_pre_preview, this.options);
            if (this.edit) {
                View view2 = fileHolder.mItem_file_ok;
                if (hideImageView.isEnable()) {
                    i = 0;
                }
                view2.setVisibility(i);
                view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        boolean z;
                        int i = 0;
                        HideImageExt hideImageExt = hideImageView;
                        if (hideImageView.isEnable()) {
                            z = false;
                        } else {
                            z = true;
                        }
                        hideImageExt.setEnable(z);
                        View view = fileHolder.mItem_file_ok;
                        if (!hideImageView.isEnable()) {
                            i = 8;
                        }
                        view.setVisibility(i);
                        PicHideAdapter.this.updateSelect();
                    }
                });
                view.setOnLongClickListener(null);
                return;
            }
            fileHolder.mItem_file_ok.setVisibility(8);
            view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent();
                    intent.setClass(PicHideAdapter.this.context, PhotoPreViewActivity.class);
                    intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("list", (ArrayList)
                    PicHideAdapter.this.mList_HideFile);
                    intent.putExtra("id", position);
                    PicHideAdapter.this.context.startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
            view.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {
                public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                    PicHideAdapter.this.doVibrator(PicHideAdapter.this.context);
                    PicHideAdapter.this.mOnListern.onLongClick(hideImageView);
                    return false;
                }
            });
        } else if (data instanceof GroupImageExt) {
            final GroupImageExt groupImageView = (GroupImageExt) data;
            fileHolder.mItem_file_ok.setVisibility(8);
            fileHolder.mImg_pre_preview.setImageResource(R.drawable.folder);
            view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (PicHideAdapter.this.edit) {
                        PicHolder fileHolder = (PicHolder) v.getTag();
                        groupImageView.setEnable(!groupImageView.isEnable());
                    } else if (PicHideAdapter.this.mOnListern != null) {

                        PicHideAdapter.this.mOnListern.openHolder(groupImageView);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }

    public void setHitFiles(List < ?>listGroup, List < ?>listFile, int groupID) {
        this.mList_Group = GroupImageExt.transList((List < GroupImage > ) listGroup);
        this.mList_HideFile = HideImageExt.transList((List < HideImage > ) listFile);
        setGroup(groupID);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you setting any params to your layout at runtime? If yes then please post that code.

Comment: no, i'm not setting params at runtime

Comment: Are you using listview or something? please provide some relevant code.

Comment: show your xml with the relative layout? or the code where you use it?

Comment: Why are you using this `convertView.setLayoutParams(this.params);`? Try running code without this line.

Comment: i tried without it but not hope.! @mayurGajra

Comment: Then i think i need to have a look at your complete code.Please provide your activity code,adapter code Xml and java both if you are ok with it.

Comment: i have added all class and code!

Answer (score 0):

```
   LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(-2, -2);

    lp.setMargins(margin, margin, margin, margin);

    setLayoutParams(lp);
```

resolved..by removing this param